# Why is indicated distance so long? Html, css

Tags: html, css

Why is indicated distance so long? Here is an image:
[image]

Here is the full code:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 2vw;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer0 {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: calc(100%-80px);
  height: 230px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  background-color: #960017;
  color: #eee;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.footer0 a:link,
.footer0 a:hover,
.footer0 a:visited,
.footer0 a:active {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  text-indent: 50px;
  margin: 5%;
  text-align: justify;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1205px) {
  .code0 {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #4a3728;
    /* here is the place to define the border color, the box shadow is gray anyway */
    width: 1200px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
  }
}

.r {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<body class="code0">

  <div class="main">
    Welcome to the site.
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="footer r" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Copyright <b>Institutum Latinum Romae</b> &copy; 2022-2022</p>
  </div>
```

My attempt: play with the margin-bottom of the internal element, padding-bottom of the external element. It didn't work out.

I use a nice trick called code0. It enables displaying on huge screens with a nice look. It creates a rectangle on huge screens where the page is inside of it.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about providing a [mcve] (emphasis on the *minimal*)

Comment: Minimum example provided now.

Comment: You don't have any content below the footer. That space seems to be the remaining space of the browser's height. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve the distance in the image to be 20px.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough content. So you need to give the body a `min-height: 100vh` and apply `flexbox` + `flex-direction: column` to it. Then you can push the footer to the bottom by using `margin-top: auto`. That will consume all remaining space and place the footer at the bottom even when the content is insufficient to fill the viewport.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 2vw;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer0 {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: calc(100%-80px);
  height: 230px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  background-color: #960017;
  color: #eee;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.footer0 a:link,
.footer0 a:hover,
.footer0 a:visited,
.footer0 a:active {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  text-indent: 50px;
  margin: 5%;
  text-align: justify;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1205px) {
  .code0 {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #4a3728;
    /* here is the place to define the border color, the box shadow is gray anyway */
    width: 1200px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  }
}

.r {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<body class="code0">

  <div class="main">
    Welcome to the site.
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="footer r" style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Copyright <b>Institutum Latinum Romae</b> &copy; 2022-2022</p>
  </div>
</body>
```